# How do I make child processes in Win32 so that they show up as nested in Task Manager?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a Win32 C++ application. I'm trying to launch one or several child processes with `CreateProcess`. I want the children to close when the parent does.

I achieved this by creating a job and enabling `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE`:

```cpp
HANDLE hJob = CreateJobObject(NULL, NULL);

JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION extendedInfo;
ZeroMemory(&extendedInfo, sizeof(extendedInfo));
extendedInfo.BasicLimitInformation.LimitFlags =
    JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE;

SetInformationJobObject(
        hJob, JOBOBJECTINFOCLASS::JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation,
        &extendedInfo, sizeof(extendedInfo));
```

Then adding the current (parent) and created (child) process to this job:

```cpp
// assign parent to job
AssignProcessToJobObject(hJob, GetCurrentProcess());

// launch child with no inherited handles
PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo;
ZeroMemory(&procInfo, sizeof(procInfo));
STARTUPINFOA startInfo;
ZeroMemory(&startInfo, sizeof(startInfo));
startInfo.cb = sizeof(startInfo);
startInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
bool success = CreateProcessA(NULL,
                              "test.exe",  // command line
                              NULL,     // process security attributes
                              NULL,   // primary thread security attributes
                              FALSE,  // handles are inherited
                              0,      // creation flags
                              NULL,   // use parent's environment
                              NULL,   // use parent's current directory
                              &startInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer
                              &procInfo);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION
// assign child to job
AssignProcessToJobObject(hJob, procInfo.hProcess);
```

This works, but the parent app and the child app (`main.exe` and `test.exe`) show up as two unrelated processes in the task manager:

[image]

[image]

(Even though closing main.exe will close test.exe).

What am I doing differently than, say, Microsoft Teams or Chrome, which both have nested processes?

[image]

Comment: Chrome is open source, just take a look.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Good suggestion, but the chromium codebase is over a GB to clone (with `--depth=1`) and I am entirely unfamiliar with it. I'll maybe still try to see if I can `grep` a `CreateProcess` call somewhere in this monstrosity once it finishes cloning though...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt For this, one would need to know _where_ to look and _what_ to look for :) Which is why this question was asked here, I suppose...

Comment: @MHebes You could also search online: https://source.chromium.org/chromium

Comment: See __CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP__ here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags

Comment: @RichardCritten so in my example, would you need some launcher application whose only job is to `CreateProcess` the `main.exe` with `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`, and then `main` could launch `test`? Or is there a way to have the current process make its own group?

Comment: I could not get `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` working. I tested having a separate launcher process that launches `main.exe` with the flag, as I described, and I get the same behavior.

Comment: The things you talk about here are "tasks", not processes. Use Process Explorer and you will see the real process tree. `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` is a console/terminal flag.

Comment: @MHebes you are misinterpreting what TaskManager is showing you.  It is not displaying nested processes. It is grouping multiple windows that have been created by different processes of a single executable file, not spawned from the same parent process.

Comment: @Anders Thank you! I thought I might be misunderstanding. Process Explorer does indeed show `test.exe` nested under `main.exe`. Could you point me to some documentation about what you're referring to? "Task" is such an overloaded term in the windows documentation that it's proving hard to google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly what Task manager is doing is not documented.

In Windows 8 it does not group child processes, it only organizes based on a process having a window or by being "special".

[How does Task Manager categorize processes as App, Background Process, or Windows Process?](https://web.archive.org/web/20190206012140/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171219-00/?p=97606):

> These are terms that Task Manager simply made up. The system itself doesn’t really care what kind of processes they are.
>
> If the process has a visible window, then Task Manager calls it an “App”.
>
> If the process is marked as critical, then Task Manager calls it a “Windows Process”.
>
> Otherwise, Task Manager calls it a “Background Process”.

(I don't believe this is 100% accurate, it clearly knows about services and I suspect it might hard-code some names)

In Windows 10 it tries harder to group things together but I don't exactly know what it is doing.

- It is often (but not always) able to tie the conhost.exe child to its parent console application.
- The new fancy store/packaged versions of Notepad and Paint have all their processes in a single group. The same does not happen with Notepad2 even though it has a Application Model ID set. Neither does it apply to Wordpad (even when one is a child of the other). I also tried setting an AMUI in a little test application and neither process wide AMUI nor per-HWND AMUI seems to trigger the grouping.
- A job object does not seem to enable grouping.
- Depending on your version, Edge might use a special API to [tell Task manager about its processes](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2021/10/12/improving-edge-processes-task-manager/).

In conclusion, I don't know what exactly what it is looking for but Packaged applications and App Containers seem to often trigger it.

Answer (score 1):

To make it visible as a child process in the task manager, you have to set the CreateNoWindow property to false and UseShellExecute property to false in the StartInfo property before starting the process.

```
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

This tells the process to create a new window for the child process and to use the command line to start the process instead of using the shell to start the process.
This will now create the child process as a new visible process in the task manager, and it will be shown under the tree of the main process.

Comment: What are you talking about? The STARTUPINFO structs do not have any such parameters. I would advise you to research before you post.